# AngularJS. Prevent loading JSON data twice when using caching

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers - `ParentCtrl` and `ChildCtrl`.

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

They using same service method to get data.  Data is cached (using `cache:true` parameter of `$http` service).

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory("myService", [
        '$http',
        function $http) {
        return {
            getMyData: function () {
               return $http.get(url, {cache: true}).then(function (response) {
                  return data = response.
            });
```

So the problem is that this 2 controllers begins to work simultaneously - this  means `myService#getMyData` method can be called twice, i.e. 2 round trips to server. But I want only one round trip, so `ChildCtrl` will get result from cache.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Hey MT, did you try this solution in your app? Or did you have any concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing some synchronization structure, I would add it to the routing as a prefetched data (viewModel):

```
   $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        controller: homeController,
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
        resolve: {
            sharedData: function($http, myService) {
                var sharedPromise = myService.getMyData().then(function(results) {
                    return results;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Then in your controllers, at least in the root, you can reference the shared data just as if you had a reference to the service:

```
function homeController($scope, $http, sharedData) {}
```

Excuse the pseudo code, but it will allow you at least to be guaranteed that the reference data was fetch once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that I'm calling service with parameters. And the default parameters are setup inside controller and then I'm calling service. So its mean I need to duplicate this default parameters in COntroller and also when defining my routes using `$routeProvider`. I believe it will make my code harder to read.

Comment: Assuming the child controller is passing the same parameters, which it should given the issue of multiple simultaneous calls, then why not utilize directives to pass in the values of the parent controllers results of the myService call to the child controller through data attributes or just leverage sharing scope itself?

Comment: Using directive - is one of the option, but I think its not good to create directive for thing that will be used only once. Finally I just re-read `$http` service documentation, and the answer is that `$http` handle situations with multiple AJAX calls:  if 2 calls made in one time, then second call will just wait until result from first round-trip will be fetched and cached. So no need to synchronization. Anyway thanks for trying to help. upvote